# Get the row id of the current item in ListView

Tags: java, android, checkbox, onclick

This is my list view item:
[image]

I want to put an OnClickListener on the Checkbox. But I need to get the list item that the CheckBox is in, via row id. How can I do that in the `onClick` method.

Comment: or the...? something is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the bindView method, you have to put a click listener on each checkbox